# QiChat ^switchFocus does not stop dialog

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

On Pepper, 2.5.7.1, I'm using a .top dialog script as the main Interactive application to call other apps on the robot.

These work fine

```
[...] ^run(User/epicsax-6f83fc/behavior_1)
[...] ^run(User/taichidemo-c66a80/behavior_1)
[...] ^pCall(ALVolumeSlider.increaseVolume())
```

However if the application has to run something that is Interactive, the meditation application runs simultaneously:

```
u:(meditation) okay ^switchFocus(meditation-8806ca/behavior_1)
```

when this executes, the robot is still in dialog mode, eyes flashing blue and other still responding in accordance with the .top script.
I would expect that the first application would stop.

If I run this SSH command while the main dialog is running, I get the expected behavior where the dialog stops:

```
qicli call ALAutonomousLife.switchFocus meditation-8806ca/behavior_1
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the .top file with these dialogue loaded? In collaborative dialogue, as a box in a behavior, dynamically loaded from script? If it's from a behavior, is that behavior also an Autonomous Life behavior? (i.e. with interactive tag, started with switch focus, etc.) If you started it with ALBehaviorManager.startBehavior then it won't automatically be stopped when you switch focus).

Some approaches:

- Try `^pCall(ALAutonomousLife.switchFocus("meditation-8806ca/behavior_1"))` - should be equivalent, but you never know
- call qicli call ALDialog.getActivatedTopics so you can know if your topic is still running (it shouldn't be!)

Comment: The .top is loaded as non-collaborative, in a dialog box. The program is Interactive.
I tried ^pCall( switch focus) but the second behavior is never loaded. Calling getActivatedTopics shows that the topic is still running.